# Loop return one result in conditioner query

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to fetch data from database in code-igniter .Bur this loop return only one loop .

```
$userchatData = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat'))->result_array();

 foreach($userchatData as $key => $userdata)
 {
       $userdatas[]= array(
                  'chat_id' => $userdata['chat_id'],
                  'chat_from' => $userdata['chat_from'],
                  'created_date' => $userdata['created_date']
           );
 }
 $data['ChatdatabyId'] = $userdatas;
 $data['responseCode'] = '200';

 $data['responseMessage'] = 'User listing successfully';

 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: update for Complete Function, there is one  extra } above json_encode

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having. Can you share the data inside the array, and also what you expect this loop to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `$userdatas=array();` outside the loop. It is inside the loop that's why it overrides the data and returns the last record.

```
$userchatData = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat'))->result_array();
  $userdatas = array();
  foreach($userchatData as $key => $userdata){
  $userdatas[]= array(
                 'chat_id' => $userdata['chat_id'],
                 'chat_from' => $userdata['chat_from'],
                 'created_date' => $userdata['created_date']
                 );
  }
   $data['ChatdatabyId'] =$userdatas;
   $data['responseCode'] = '200';
   $data['responseMessage'] = 'User listing successfully';
   echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Here I define $userdatas = array();  and assigning data array to $userdatas[]; It create index 0 , 1, 2, and so on.

Comment: $userdatas[0]= $data,$userdatas[1]= $data,$userdatas[2]= $data, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you :

```
$userchatData = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('usres_chat'))->result_array();

foreach($userchatData as $key => $userdata)
{
    $userdatas[$key]['chat_id'] = $userdata['chat_id'];
    $userdatas[$key]['chat_from'] = $userdata['chat_from'];
    $userdatas[$key]['created_date'] = $userdata['created_date'];
}

/*print_r($userdatas); output here*/

$data['ChatdatabyId'] = $userdatas;
$data['responseCode'] = '200';

$data['responseMessage'] = 'User listing successfully';
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: pradeep@pradeep this code is showing error unexpected  "=>"

Comment: sorry it should be = not => my mistake copy paste error

Comment: just curious, is my code is not working for you, is there something wrong